# Why aren't hearing tests offered, in the same way as an eye test?

Tags: united-kingdom, benefits

In the UK, employee benefits often include a paid-for or reimbursable sight test, once every 2 years. Packages usually provide £200, for the cost of an eye test and eyewear required to perform your duties.

Why is the same not offered with respect to a hearing test?

Comment: Because as they age almost everyone eventually ends up needing glasses.  That's not true of hearing aids.

Comment: To those who marked this question as opinion-based; can you explain why, please?

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is almost certainly driven by the legal requirement to provide eye-tests and glasses if employees use digital screen equipment. Given how many people that covers these days, it's probably easier to do it for all employees. There is no similar legal requirement for hearing tests, probably for the reasons in the answers below.

Comment: What does this have to do with the workplace?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek I thought the question was pretty clear.

Comment: @spikey_richie - you are right.  I misread the question.  Probably because I thought the UK had healthcare that wasn't tied to employment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Society has weird divisions for healthcare**

Plenty of countries have universal  health care, except for eyes and teeth. In Canada, feet are only partially covered. In the UK, [hearing is considered part of universal health care](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/hearing-tests/), so it is covered. [Eyes are not unless you are in a special group.](https://www.nhs.uk/nhs-services/opticians/free-nhs-eye-tests-and-optical-vouchers/)

So you should already be covered under the NHS for hearing.

Comment: The eye tests are covered by your employer if you work with DSE (display screen equipment). So thats everyone who uses a computer. I wonder if in particularly loud industries hearing tests are offered?

Answer (score 9):

Hearing tests and basic hearing aids are [freely available](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/hearing-tests/) under the NHS to all - on the other hand, free eye tests and prescription lenses are [limited by age or to people with specific diagnosed conditions](https://www.nhs.uk/nhs-services/opticians/free-nhs-eye-tests-and-optical-vouchers/).

UK employers are [required](https://www.hse.gov.uk/msd/dse/eye-tests.htm) to pay for periodic eye tests (once a year or two), and then contribute towards prescribed lenses if correction is deemed necessary for specific types of work.